# Trigger Login when click on button Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am working on oracle apex interface for user profile.
   Is there a way to trigger login when click on a button (update my profile) and then redirect to designated page after login.

thanks

Comment: please check what the apex tag refers to, then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the My Profile page's Authentication property to "Page requires authentication", then when the unauthenticated user clicks on the My Profile button (which tries to navigate to the My Profile page) they will be diverted to the login page.  As soon as they have logged in APEX will redirect them back to the My Profile page automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if deep linking is enable in both aplication and page profil level.